# Filter transactions per block 50 BTC or Higher

Tags: blockchain, blocktrail

I'm using the [blocktrail python api](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/python), to try and display transactions above 50 BTC per block for a visualization project. I think I'm almost there but can anyone help me understand where I'm stuck?

```
client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="MY_APIKEY", api_secret="MY_APISECRET", network="BTC", testnet=false)

def getLargeTxs():
  block = client.block_latest()
  transactions = client.block_transactions(block)['data']
  over_50btc = [ item for item in transactions if blocktrail.to_btc( item['estimated_value'] ) > 50.0 ]
  return over_50btc
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the problem with this program? What happens when you run it?